# Make something higher

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Can I say :” make something five meters higher “ or “ make something higher by five meters “ ? I mean Can I use “ five meters “ in these ways ?

Comment: In *some* contexts, you could reasonably speak of [***heightening** the wall*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22heightening+the+wall%22), for example. But this would very often be seen as "awkward", so it's probably best never to use the verb ***to heighten*** at all. Stick with ***make** [something] **higher***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of those uses are grammatical. The first is a bit more natural to a native speaker, but both make sense.

In some cases, though, you might want to use "Five metres **taller** instead. You'd normally use "Five metres **higher**" if you were speaking of something abstract, like a distance to be climbed or jumped, or "Five metres **taller**" when speaking of something discrete and physical.

> "We need to make the rope climb five metres **higher**."
>
> "We need to make the rope climb **higher** by five metres."

vs

> "We need to build the wall five metres **taller**."

You might also use **put** instead of **make** if you're speaking of placing a single item at a specified height:

> "We need to **put** the basketball hoop five metres higher."

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to say, "Make it *higher*," for objects placed at a certain height -- but it sounds rather juvenile, as if the person didn't know the verb "raise" (or its synonyms).

> **Raise** it by 5 meters please?

For objects of a certain *height*, which you want to increase, the preferred expression is, "Make it taller".